# Gaining weight - carbohydrate and proteins?

Tags: protein, weight-gain

I would like to gain some more weight before the summer. How would I achieve that the most effectively?

My current diet is something along the lines of:

**7:00 AM**

- Yoghurt and muesli
- Banana
- Protein shake

**10:00 AM**

- 3 slices of brown bread with either:

  - Peanutbutter
  - Chicken
  - Roast beef

**01:00 PM**

- 3 - 4 slices of brown bread with either:

  - Roast beef
  - Coconut
  - Cheese

**04:00 PM**

- 3 slices of brown bread with either:

  - Peanutbutter
  - Chicken
  - Roast beef

**06:00 PM**

- Diner

**08:00 PM**

- Protein shake
- Sometimes a banana

And I work out on Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday/Friday.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gaining weight is as easy as eating more or exercising less. All you need to do is bring the caloric consumption above your caloric expenditure. It doesn't matter if you eat more carbs, protein, or fats. That being said, fats have the highest caloric density.

The best way to lose weight is to basically eat your normal diet, but less. I would suggest, if you're serious about gaining weight, to eat the same things you are eating, but increase the quantity. The more you eat, the more you gain.

Comment: What's the most efficient if you want to gain muscle? Do you need to eat loads or is it all about having enough protein to recover?

Comment: Lift heavy and take a multi. Yes, you'll need to eat enough to fuel the muscle growth. People disagree as to how much protein you need.

Comment: So instead of doing 10-12 reps I would also have to lower my reps to 6-8?

Comment: @Kevin - you need a good book on bodybuilding: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/865/35

Comment: @Sparafusile: Haha, thanks for the help :). Appreciate it!

Comment: @Sparafusile - "Lift heavy and take a multi" - you aware?

Comment: @Nick - That info costs brah, but for you only tree fiddy.

Comment: @Spara - repped

Comment: Obviously, getting all your calories from ice cream and soda will not give you lean gains. And if there's a wrong way of doing it, there's also a right way. My best tip is to look at the people who have actually gotten to the point you want to be and imitate them.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your diet, you are probably not taking in that many calories. Most of what you're eating is pretty lean, and it doesn't seem like you're eating that much of it. If you want to gain weight, it's simple - eat more! That's it! Here's a look at a diet I used to gain 25 lbs. in 3 months:

7am - 6 whole eggs, 1 cup of oats, banana, protein shake, multi-vitamin

10am - Breakfast burrito w/ 2 eggs, ham, sausage, bacon, cheese, hashbrown, ketchup wrapped in a tortilla

12pm - Lunch (whatever leftovers I had) ex. - Chicken breast w/ brown rice

3pm - Yogurt and peanuts

6pm - Protein shake

9pm - Dinner - ex. Steak and a salad (spinach with olive oil and balsamic vinegar)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is only to gain weight on the scale, then I agree that you need to eat more calories.  However, I imagine you would like to gain muscle rather than fat.  In that case, it matters very much whether it comes from protein, carbs, or fat.

It would help to know how much you weigh, and how much weight you want to gain.  Also if you're exercising by doing cardio and/or lifting weights.

In regards to your diet... Chicken, peanut butter, roast beef, cheese, and coconut are not interchangeable.  Chicken and roast beef are proteins.  Peanut butter, coconut, and cheese are fats.  Brown bread is not the best carbohydrate source.  I would suggest brown rice and/or sweet potatoes instead.  I suggest getting a protein with every meal for lean mass gain.